# Custom MKAnnotationView stopped working after enabling ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkannotation

I had custom MKAnnotationView implemented and it worked correctly before enabling ARC.
initWithAnnotation method was implemented like this:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
    self.hasBuiltInDraggingSupport = [[MKAnnotationView class] instancesRespondToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"isDraggable")];

    if (self.hasBuiltInDraggingSupport)
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnView  = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        self = (AnnotationView*)pinAnnView;
        if (self) 
        [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setDraggable:") withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    }
    self.canShowCallout = YES;
    return self;
}
```

After enabling ARC I started to receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the following line:

```
self = (AnnotationView*)pinAnnView;
```

Currently i have no idea what happens.

Comment: I took this code from example on how to create custom draggable pin. And it worked fine until i enabled ARC. But after taking some time i solved it by replacing "self = (AnnotationView*)pinAnnView" with "self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifyer]"

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that with ARC the variable is released as soon it comes out of scope and so it never leaves the function. I have the same problem I have not yet found a solution of, though.